# Kafka retry in batch listener behaving differently in 2 scenarios

Tags: spring-kafka

Spring-boot : 2.7.1,
Spring-kafka : 2.8.7

I tested kafka retry with error handling in my local where I publish around 1500 messages and I listen in batches and process them in loop (Only 1 topic which has 1 partition). It is working as expected, that is the message is retried to process again and upon exhaustion of retries it is sent to error topic.

KafkaConfig

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate,
                (consumer, e) -> new TopicPartition("errortopic", -1));
        FixedBackOff fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(10,2);
        DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer, fixedBackOff);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler);
        return factory;
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = getDefaultParams();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 20);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

Listener

```
    @Autowired
    private MyService myservice;
    
    
    @KafkaListener(id="sample-listener", topics= {"topic1", "topic2"})
    public void listen(final List<ConsumerRecord<String, String> records) {
        
        for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record: records)
        try {
            myservice.process(record.value());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new BatchListenerFailedException("Failure in processing message", record);
        }
    }
```

Service

```
@Transactional
public void process(String record){
count++;
if(count == 2 || count ==3){
throw new RuntimeException();
}

}
```

When I run it in dev environment, where we have 2 topics and each topic has 64 partitions (messages will be around 100k an hour), the message is not retried at all.

Comment: DEBUG logging should help.